# SQL Reactivation Revenue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a query that will Sum Reactivation Revenue from a given date on. Currently I have the following query;

```
    SELECT advertisable, EXTRACT(YEAR from day), EXTRACT(MONTH from day), ROUND(SUM(cost)/1e6)  FROM adcube dac
WHERE advertisable_eid IN 

(SELECT advertisable FROM adcube dac 
GROUP BY advertisable HAVING SUM(cost)/1e6 > 100)

GROUP BY advertisable, EXTRACT(YEAR from day), EXTRACT(MONTH from day)
ORDER BY advertisable, EXTRACT(YEAR from day), EXTRACT(MONTH from day)
```

From this i then export to excel and check accounts thay have stopped spending for 4 months and then reactivated. I then track the new revenue from the new reactivtion month.

Is it possible to get an SQL query to do this without need of Excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the four months is actually present in the data, you can do this using window functions.  You can find *N* things in a row by taking the difference between two `row_numbers()`.  Here is the idea:

```
with t as (
      SELECT advertisable, EXTRACT(YEAR from day) as yy, EXTRACT(MONTH from day) as mon, 
             ROUND(SUM(cost)/1e6) as val
      FROM adcube dac
      WHERE advertisable_eid IN (SELECT advertisable
                                 FROM adcube dac 
                                 GROUP BY advertisable
                                 HAVING SUM(cost)/1e6 > 100
                                )
      GROUP BY advertisable, EXTRACT(YEAR from day), EXTRACT(MONTH from day)
     )
select advertisable, min(yy * 10000 + mon) as yyyymm
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by advertisable order by yy, mon) -
              row_number() over (partition by advertisable, val order by yy, mon)
             ) as grp
      from t
     )
group by advertisable, grp, val
having count(*) >= 4 and val = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this query looks to do the trick. Would I insert and additional query at the end to so advertisables that have = 0 for 4 counts but then spent again after 4?

Comment: @user3207341 . . . That would be rather different from your original question.  You should ask that in another question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I've resubmitted the question, do you think it would be difficult to answer? I was hoping to branch out the filter from your original answer?