# Reactivation revenue SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently am using the following query;

```
ROUND(SUM(cost)/1e6) as val
      FROM adcube dac
      WHERE adverwith t as (
      SELECT advertisable, EXTRACT(YEAR from day) as yy, EXTRACT(MONTH from day) as mon, 
          tisable_eid IN (SELECT advertisable
                                 FROM adcube dac 
                                 GROUP BY advertisable
                                 HAVING SUM(cost)/1e6 > 100
                                )
      GROUP BY advertisable, EXTRACT(YEAR from day), EXTRACT(MONTH from day)
     )
select advertisable, min(yy * 10000 + mon) as yyyymm
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by advertisable order by yy, mon) -
              row_number() over (partition by advertisable, val order by yy, mon)
             ) as grp
      from t
     )
group by advertisable, grp, val
having count(*) >= 4 and val = 0
```

This gives me the month and year the advertisable stops and = 0 for >= 4 months.
would it be possible to insert an additional query at the end so advertisables that have = 0 for 4 counts but then spent again after 4? i.e. track the month the advertisable re-activated?

EDIT: this is a follow-up of [SQL Reactivation Revenue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887082)

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? That's different database engines.

Comment: Why the `mysql` tag? The query clearly does not run there.

Comment: I removed the tag for him

Comment: Sorry guys my mistake didn't mean to include mysql